# scroll with up and down keys in autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I created an autocomplete input that compares the input with available values.
It is also possible to navigate trough the result list with the up and down arrow keys.
This is achieved with adding classes that adds a color to the current item.
However when the list is too big there appears a scrollbar but the navigation using the arrow keys doesn't scroll with it.
How can I achieve this?

I tried to use:

```
x.scrollTop = 50;
```

But it hasn't any results.
This is my code

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      var overlay = document.createElement("DIV");
      overlay.setAttribute("id", "autocomplete-overlay");
      $(".wrapper").append(overlay);
      var limit = 40;
      var current = 0;
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i][1].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase() && current < limit) {
          current++;
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<img src='"+arr[i][2]+"' style='height: 30px;width: 30px;margin-right: 10px;border-radius: 50%;object-fit: cover;'>";
          b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arr[i][1].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i][1].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i][1] + "'>";
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i][3] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              var place = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
              window.location = place;
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
        else if(arr[i][1].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) > -1  && current < limit  ){
          current++;
            /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<img src='"+arr[i][2]+"' style='height: 30px;width: 30px;margin-right: 10px;border-radius: 50%;object-fit: cover;'>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i][1].substr(0, arr[i][1].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()));
          b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arr[i][1].substr(arr[i][1].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()), val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i][1].substr(arr[i][1].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) + val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i][1] + "'>";
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i][3] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              var place = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
              window.location = place;
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
        if(currentFocus > 16){
          x.scrollTop = 50;
        }
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          var place = x[currentFocus].getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
          if (x) window.location = place;
        }
      }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
    if(document.getElementById("autocomplete-overlay")){
      document.getElementById("autocomplete-overlay").remove();
    }
    
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if(e.target.id != "search-portal"){
        closeAllLists(e.target);
      }
      
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var companies = [ ["3", "test1", "company1.png", "company1.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"]
];
/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("search-portal"), companies);
```

```css
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}


#newc td, th{
  text-align: left;
}
#newc a{
  color: black;
}


.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 698px;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
  font-size: 13px;
}

/*when hovering an item:*/
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

/*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group autocomplete sidebar-form" id="searchform" style="overflow: visible; width:-webkit-fill-available; margin-left: 10px; border: none !important; margin: 6px 20px 6px 190px !important; max-width: 600px;">
            
              <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" id="search-portal" placeholder="Search"/>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
               
              </span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an autocomplete script very similar to this, can't test without data, but It's working right for me.

Check the `addActive` function:

1. If item is hidden on top, scroll its container to the item offset top.
2. If item is hidden on bottom, scroll its container to the item offset top + item height.

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      var overlay = document.createElement("DIV");
      overlay.setAttribute("id", "autocomplete-overlay");
      $(".wrapper").append(overlay);
      var limit = 40;
      var current = 0;
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i][1].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase() && current < limit) {
          current++;
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<img src='"+arr[i][2]+"' style='height: 30px;width: 30px;margin-right: 10px;border-radius: 50%;object-fit: cover;'>";
          b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arr[i][1].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i][1].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i][1] + "'>";
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i][3] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              var place = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
              window.location = place;
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
        else if(arr[i][1].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) > -1  && current < limit  ){
          current++;
            /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<img src='"+arr[i][2]+"' style='height: 30px;width: 30px;margin-right: 10px;border-radius: 50%;object-fit: cover;'>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i][1].substr(0, arr[i][1].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()));
          b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arr[i][1].substr(arr[i][1].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()), val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i][1].substr(arr[i][1].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) + val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i][1] + "'>";
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i][3] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              var place = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
              window.location = place;
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
        if(currentFocus > 16){
          x.scrollTop = 50;
        }
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          var place = x[currentFocus].getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
          if (x) window.location = place;
        }
      }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");

    /* ******** Show item ************* */
 if(x[currentFocus].offsetTop < x[currentFocus].parentNode.scrollTop) {
  // Hidden on top, move scroll to show item
  // Just to the top of item
  x[currentFocus].parentNode.scrollTop = x[currentFocus].offsetTop;
 } else if(x[currentFocus].offsetTop > (x[currentFocus].parentNode.scrollTop + x[currentFocus].parentNode.clientHeight) - x[currentFocus].clientHeight) {
  // Hidden on bottom, move scroll to top of item + item height
  x[currentFocus].parentNode.scrollTop = x[currentFocus].offsetTop - (x[currentFocus].parentNode.clientHeight - x[currentFocus].clientHeight);
 }
    /* ******** Show item ************* */

  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
    if(document.getElementById("autocomplete-overlay")){
      document.getElementById("autocomplete-overlay").remove();
    }
    
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if(e.target.id != "search-portal"){
        closeAllLists(e.target);
      }
      
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var companies = [ ["3", "test1", "company1.png", "company1.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"], ["4", "test4", "company4.png", "company4.com"]
];
/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("search-portal"), companies);
```

```css
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}


#newc td, th{
  text-align: left;
}
#newc a{
  color: black;
}


.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 698px;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
  font-size: 13px;
}

/*when hovering an item:*/
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

/*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group autocomplete sidebar-form" id="searchform" style="overflow: visible; width:-webkit-fill-available; margin-left: 10px; border: none !important; margin: 6px 20px 6px 190px !important; max-width: 600px;">
            
              <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" id="search-portal" placeholder="Search"/>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
               
              </span>
            </div>
```